# Double "derjenige" and punctuation

Tags: word-order, punctuation

Here is a sentence of my own making. I would like to know whether the punctuation is correct here.

> (…), ein bitterer Kampf zwischen **denjenigen**, die überfüttert werden, und **denjenigen**, die zu kurz gekommen sind.

I'm not sure whether it is necessary to repeat "denjenigen" and whether the comma before "und" is even necessary.

Comment: The main clause seems to lack a verb, so the example falls short of a  *sentence*; more context would be helpful to decide, what you are trying to express; I'm not sure, whether singular or plural for the involved person(s) is desired.

Comment: @guidot It does not. It can be taken as an ellipsis used as a description of an image.

Comment: @OranMatheus: assuming you are referring to the lack of a verb:  you are partially right with the version after the significant editing of the example.

Answer (score 5):

The punctuation is correct. But there are other issues.

> Ein bitterer Kampf zwischen denjenigen, **die** überfüttert werden, und denjenigen, **die** zu kurz gekommen **sind**

- The relative pronoun of the subordinate sentences must be in this case their subject, and thus be in nominative case, thus the plural 'die'.
- The Perfekt of 'zu kurz kommen' is formed with 'sein' instead of 'haben'.

You can replace "denjenigen" also by the shorter and slightly lower register "denen". Either case you cannot leave out one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @planetmaker already said:

> Ein bitterer Kampf zwischen denjenigen, den überfüttert werden, und denjenigen, den zu kurz gekommen haben.

This is actually not a sentence. At best it is a big *Nominalphrase* of a sentence yet to be built. Something like:

> Ein bitterer Kampf zwischen [...] *wurde geführt*.

or

> Ein bitterer Kampf zwischen [...] *beginnt*.

in other words: you need to add at least a *Prädikat* (that is: some *Verb*) to have a sentence, maybe  other parts (objects, ...) too. All the "other parts" are optional and you can leave them out, but a predicate is essential.

PS: I only see now, that @guidot made the same observation in his comment.